# Multi replacement in the same node with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My input is:

```
<w:body>
 <w:p>
 <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
  </w:pPr>
 <w:r><w:t>1274394 The milk costs , $1.99 [12] test Figure 1, Table 1</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r><w:t>sample text Figure 1 and [1]</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
</w:body>
```

I would like to get the output like below using XSLT "analyze-string"

```
<w:body>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
   <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
 </w:pPr>
<w:r><w:t>1274394 The milk costs , $1.99 <ref>[12]</ref> test <fig>Figure 1</fig>, <tab>Table 1</tab></w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r><w:t>sample text Figure 1 and [1]</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
</w:body>
```

The XSLT is below:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:t/text()">
 <xsl:variable name="phase1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="fig" />
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="phase2">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="tab" />
 </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$phase1" mode="ref" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="text()" mode="fig">
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Figure (\d{{1,2}})">
 <xsl:matching-substring>
  <fig>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </fig>
 </xsl:matching-substring>
 <xsl:non-matching-substring>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="ref">
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\[(\d{{1,2}})\]">
 <xsl:matching-substring>
  <ref>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </ref>
 </xsl:matching-substring>
 <xsl:non-matching-substring>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="tab">
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Table (\d{{1,2}})">
 <xsl:matching-substring>
  <tab>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </tab>
 </xsl:matching-substring>
 <xsl:non-matching-substring>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="ref">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="ref"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using above XSLT I could replace Fig and ref, to replace table I am using Phase2 variable but I'm not getting output, is there any alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have missed the point of the pipe-line design. In a pipe-line, you feed the output of one stage/ phase into the input of the next.

**If you wish to retain the same pipe-line design, then use this XSLT 2.0 style-sheet...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:w="www"
  exclude-result-prefixes='xsl fn'>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
      
<xsl:template match="w:t/text()">
 <xsl:variable name="phase1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="fig" />
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="phase2">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$phase1" mode="tab" />
 </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$phase2" mode="ref" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="fig">
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Figure (\d{{1,2}})">
 <xsl:matching-substring>
  <fig>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </fig>
 </xsl:matching-substring>
 <xsl:non-matching-substring>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="tab">
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Table (\d{{1,2}})">
 <xsl:matching-substring>
  <tab>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </tab>
 </xsl:matching-substring>
 <xsl:non-matching-substring>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="ref">
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\[(\d{{1,2}})\]">
 <xsl:matching-substring>
  <ref>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </ref>
 </xsl:matching-substring>
 <xsl:non-matching-substring>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="tab">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="tab"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
      
<xsl:template match="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="ref">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="ref"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**However with 3 similar transforms on text nodes, I would suggest moving to a common parametrised template design, accessing a look-up table of fig/tab/ref type elements and their text patterns.** Depending on time, I may or may not update this question with a style-sheet such a design.

### Update

**Here is the commpon template designed style-sheet ...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734596"
  xmlns:w="www"
  exclude-result-prefixes='xsl fn xs so'>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
      
<xsl:template match="w:t/text()">
  <xsl:call-template name="parse-text">
   <xsl:with-param name="raw-text" select="." />
  </xsl:call-template>  
</xsl:template>

<so:markup-lexicon>
 <so:map pattern="Figure (\d{1,2})" markup="fig" />
 <so:map pattern="Table (\d{1,2})"  markup="tab" />
 <so:map pattern="\[(\d{1,2})\]"    markup="ref" />
</so:markup-lexicon>

<xsl:template name="parse-text">
 <xsl:param name="raw-text" as="xs:string" />
 <xsl:variable name="m" select="
   document('')/*/so:markup-lexicon/so:map
   [fn:matches(current(),@pattern)]" as="element()*"/>
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:when test="$m">
   <xsl:call-template name="analyze-wp-text">
    <xsl:with-param name="raw-text" select="." />
    <xsl:with-param name="markup"   select="$m[1]/@markup" />
    <xsl:with-param name="pattern"  select="$m[1]/@pattern" />
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$raw-text" />
  </xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="analyze-wp-text">
 <xsl:param name="raw-text" as="xs:string" />
 <xsl:param name="markup"   as="xs:string" />
 <xsl:param name="pattern"  as="xs:string" />
 <xsl:analyze-string select="$raw-text" regex="{$pattern}">
 <xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:element name="{$markup}">
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:matching-substring>
 <xsl:non-matching-substring>
  <xsl:call-template name="parse-text">
   <xsl:with-param name="raw-text" select="." />
  </xsl:call-template>  
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Both style-sheets have been tested with Saxon and they produce this same identical output...**

```
<w:body xmlns:w="www">
   <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
         <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
         <w:t>1274394 The milk costs , $1.99 <ref>[12]</ref> test <fig>Figure 1</fig>, <tab>Table 1</tab>
         </w:t>
      </w:r>
   </w:p>
   <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
         <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
         <w:t>sample text <fig>Figure 1</fig> and <ref>[1]</ref>
         </w:t>
      </w:r>
   </w:p>
</w:body>
```

Comment: I am not getting the output for table using the above xslt, table not getting replaced with <tab> tag.

Comment: Yes I have also tested with Saxon

Comment: See output. Both producing the <tab> tag.

Comment: Then you haven't copied the stylesheet correctly. It definitely works on Saxon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14678/discussion-between-vsenthil-and-sean-b-durkin)